# React js Multiply/divide numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uitextfield

I have Created 3 inputs fields. first text fields for price per night,second is for number of nights and the third one is for the total, after multiplying the first and second text field's values. i want these inputs to be editable as well. for example if i enter the total and the nights it should show the price per night and if i enter the price per nights and total it should show me the number of nights and also if i enter the number of nights and price per night it should show me the total amount.
Here is my UI for that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKN3R.png)

And i have a date range selector just like this .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnLUj.png) so if i select the dates from here number of nights should be calculated from these two dates and should show in the number of night text field(for example date one = 2020-03-04 and date Two = 2020-03-06 the number of nights should be 2, ). if i don't select the dates number of night should be the number i entered from that text fields and by default number of nights should be equal to 1.
so far the multiplying part is working.(text field one value x text field two value)

I am new to react js and it would mean a lot to me if someone could help me with this. i hope ya'll understand my question

```
state = {
        textOne: 0,
        texttwo: 1,
        textthree: 0,
        checkin: '',
        checkout: '',

}
```

```
 calculate = async (e,type) => {
        if(type ==='one'){
            await this.setState({
               textOne:e.target.value
           }); 
        } else if(type ==='two'){
            await this.setState({
                texttwo:e.target.value
            });
        }
        else if(type ==='three'){
            await this.setState({
                textthree:e.target.value
            });
        }
        if((this.state.textOne !=='')&&(this.state.texttwo !== '')){
            let one = this.state.textOne;
            let two = this.state.texttwo;
            let total = one * two;
            await this.setState({
                textthree:total
            });
        }if ((this.state.texttwo !=='')&&(this.state.textthree !=='')){
            let two= this.state.texttwo;
            let three = this.state.textthree
            let total = three/two;
            await this.setState({
                textone:total
            });
        }
        if ((this.state.textOne !=='')&&(this.state.textthree !=='')){
            let one= this.state.textone;
            let three = this.state.textthree
            let total = three/one;
            await this.setState({
                textone:total
            });
        }
    }
```

```
 dateSelected = (date, dateType) => {

        if (dateType === 'checkin') {
            this.setState({
                checkin: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        });

        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                checkout: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            });
        }


    };
```

```
<DatePicker
        onChange={(e) => this.dateSelected(e, 'checkout')}
/>
<DatePicker
        onChange={(e) => this.dateSelected(e, 'checkin')}
/>

<Input
     size="default"
     placeholder="0"
     onChange={(e) => this.calculate(e, 'one')}/><div>x</div>
 <Input
    size="default"
    placeholder="0"
   onChange={(e) => this.calculate(e, 'two')}
 />=
    <Input
       size="default"
       placeholder="0"
      onChange={(e) => this.calculate(e, 'three')}
  />
```

Comment: show code please.

Comment: @JoeLloyd i did only the UI part. I have no idea how to start it. if you know please tell me

Comment: I suggest you start by learning basics of react, try to imitate examples from this page (setting `input` values, handling `change` events): https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components and if it doesn't work still - show here what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Walk hi thanks for the link i will go through it.

Comment: @Walk i have updated the code i did. but i feel like its wrong!  could you please tell me weather this way correct or not

Comment: @t123 you should set values in your inputs, so for the first one add `value={this.state.textOne}`

Comment: when i run the code i get an error saying diff is undefined . what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @Walk do u know how to that calculation part? i have no idea how to start it ! so for the calculation part i have to create another method right? do you know how to call it in these text field